# Not a right construct to change Forma* to Forma

Tags: c++, instance-variables

In `main`, the compiler gives me the error that there is not a right construct to change `Forma*` to `Forma`.
The error occurs on these lines.

```
    Forma forma = new Forma(nombre "Cuadrado", color "azul");
    Rectangulo rectangulo = new Rectangulo(nombre "Rectangulo", color "Negro", ladoMayor 5, ladoMenor 3);
```

[description of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOemj.png)

Sorry about the writing, English is not my first language.
I'm new in coding and C++.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Forma {
protected:
    string nombre;
    string color;

public:
    Forma(string nombre, string color) {
        this->nombre = nombre;
        this->color = color;
    }
    string getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    string getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    void setColor(string color) {
        cout << "El nuevo color sera: " + color;
        this->color = color;
    }

    virtual string imprimir() {
        cout << "Nombre: " + nombre + "\nColor: " + color;
        return "Nombre: " + nombre + "Color: " + color;
    }
    void obtenerColor() {
        cout << "El color actual es: " + color;
    }
};
```

This is the first class no error so far

```
class Rectangulo : public Forma {
private:
    double ladoMayor;
    double ladoMenor;
    double area;
    double perimetro;
public:
    Rectangulo (string nombreForma, string color, double ladoMayor, double ladoMenor): Forma(nombreForma, color){
        this->ladoMayor = ladoMayor;
        this->ladoMenor = ladoMenor;
    }

    double getLadoMayor() { return ladoMayor; }
    double getLadoMenor() { return ladoMenor; }

    double Area() {
        cout << "El area es: " << ladoMayor * ladoMenor;
        return area;
    }
    double Perimetro() {
        cout << "El perimetro es: " << ((2 * ladoMayor) + (2 * ladoMenor));
        return perimetro;
    }
    string imprimir() {
        cout << "Nombre: " + nombre +
            "\ncolor: " + color +
            "\n Lado Mayor: " << ladoMayor <<
            "\n Lado Menor: " << ladoMenor;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Here I have a question in the function `imprimir`, if I want to return all values how do I do it?

```
class Programa_prueba {
    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        Forma forma1 = new Forma(nombre "Cuadrado", color "azul");
        Rectangulo rectangulo = new Rectangulo(nombre "Rectangulo", color "Negro", ladoMayor 5, ladoMenor 3);

        forma.imprimir();
        forma.obtenerColor();
        forma.setColor("Amarillo");
        cout << "\n";
        Rectangulo rectangulo1;
        rectangulo1.imprimir();
        rectangulo.Area();
        rectangulo.Perimetro();
    }
};
```

Comment: No need for `new`. Use `new` when you need a dynamic allocation and every other possibility this side of `malloc` has been exhausted. `Forma forma(nombre "Cuadrado", color "azul");` will do the job and cause fewer problems.

Comment: But if if you *want* the problems that come with `new`,  you need a pointer: `Forma * forma = new Forma(nombre "Cuadrado", color "azul");`

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

`Forma forma` is static memory allocation, while allocating `new` is dynamic memory allocation
You have to:

```cpp
Forma forma(nombre "Cuadrado", color "azul"); // static memory allocation
```

or:

```cpp
Forma *forma = new Forma(nombre "Cuadrado", color "azul"); // dynamic memory allocation
```

Comment: Technical note you'll rarely ever see: C++ is specified so that you don't need Stacks and Heaps.